# Encontrar tabelas que contém colunas com um prefixo

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá,

Tem alguma forma de saber em um banco de dados mysql quais tabelas possuem colunas que contém a palavra "comissao" ?

Comment: Consulte a tabela `INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS` e utilize a cláusula `WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'comissao%'`.

Comment: desculpa, sou iniciante.. pode ser mais detalhado no código?

Comment: `SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'comissao%'`

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado